# control doesn't render bootstrap fileupload on asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload

Hi I'm trying to create a file upload control and render it with bootstrap fileupload.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 v 15.1

I've added the bootstrap-fileinput from NuGet (v 4.3.9)

Code:

```
@model RecsMVC.Models.DadesKoboViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dades KoboToolbox";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <input id="input_id" name="input_id" type="file" class="file" />
    </div>
}
```

when I set the class, the autocomplete doesn't find file as a suitable class, but I can see several bootstrap-fileinput classes (file-actions, file-drop-zone...)

Thank you and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Are you referring to the `bootstrap-fileinput` package? As I don't seem to see a `bootstrap-fileupload` one.

Comment: Ooops, bat typing... I've just corrected it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Ensure Proper Dependency Referencing**

Since your classes are being rendered, it sounds like there is simply an issue with your Javascript and CSS specific references not being found.

Consider ensuring that your files related to the [bootstrap-fileinput](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput) plugin are properly referenced and appear after any items they may be dependent on (e.g. jQuery, Bootstrap, etc.):

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />

<!-- Bootstrap-FileInput -->
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap-fileinput/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/lib/bootstrap-fileinput/css/fileinput.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <input id="input_id" name="input_id" type="file" class="file" />
    </div>
}
```

If these are properly loaded, you should see your classes applied as expected:

[image]

If there is any specific initialization code that you need to apply, you can add an additional `<script>` tag and explicitly target the element as seen below:

```
$(":file").fileinput({'showUpload':false, 'previewFileType':'any'});
```

**If you have issues, use a Scripts section**

It's worth noting that if you have jQuery and Bootstrap defined within your `_Layout.cshtml` page, then you'll probably want to use a section to ensure that these are referenced *after* those dependencies as well:

```
<!-- Place this at the end of your _Layout.csthml after your existing scripts -->
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

<!-- Place this within your partial view / view -->
@section scripts {
     <script src="~/lib/bootstrap-fileinput/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>
}
```

This will allow you to more finely control *where* your scripts are rendered if you reference them within child views within a Layout.

**Consider Using A Different Package Manager**

It's worth noting that NuGet has recently moved away (or attempted to) from client-side packages in favor of using another package manager such as npm, bower, etc. You might find it easier to use one of these to pull in your package as opposed to Nuget.

Answer (score 0):

The original question was about autocomplete. Here's a solution to get autocomplete working with Bootstrap 4 in Visual Studio 2017.

It appears that Visual Studio gets its autocomplete data from the files in wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist. Refresh those files with these steps:

- From the Project menu choose "Manage Bower Packages"
- Find Bootstrap, verify the version then click install
- Delete the contents of:
  wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist
- Copy the contents of:
  bower_components\bootstrap\dist
  to:
  wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist

You will also have to change any references in code to point to the new version as well.